# CountSort Array out of index

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on am implementation of CountSort for my college class.  I made a working code, that works fine for a smaller sized array (25 values), however when I try to run this one with multiple array sizes, an arrayoutofbounds exception is thrown and I'm not quite sure why.  It seems to me like the array size shouldn't be of any problems, but any input on what is going on and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated! :)

```
import java.util.*;

public class CountSortMore
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int SIZE = 0;
    int sizeList[] = {1000, 10000, 100000, 500000, 1000000};
    int[] nums = null;
    for (int sizeI = 0; sizeI < sizeList.length; sizeI++)
    {
        SIZE = sizeList[sizeI];
        nums = new int[SIZE];

        //random num generation up to 100000
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        nums[i] = (int)(Math.random()*100000);

        //for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        //{ 
        //  System.out.print(nums[i]);
        //  System.out.println("");
        //}

        //call CountSort
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            countSort(nums, 0, SIZE -1);
        final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("For n = " + SIZE + ", execution time = " + (endTime - startTime) );

        //verify sorting
        //for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        //{
        //  System.out.print(nums[i]);
        //  System.out.println("");
        //}
    }
}

public static void countSort(int[] nums, int low, int high)
{
    int[] counts = new int[high - low +1];
    for (int x : nums)
        counts[x - low]++;
    int current = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
    {
        Arrays.fill(nums, current, current + counts[i], i + low);
        current += counts[i];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the Exception, or at least mark the line where the exception is thrown?

Comment: My apologies, it says theres an issue at line 29 and 46.

Comment: this code is littered with bugs..

Comment: you create a 0 sized array and then start assigning to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a problem here:

```
for (int x : nums)
    counts[x - low]++;
```

You are indexing the count[] array using random numbers in the range 0-99999, but your smallest array is only 1000 long.

Although I think your approach is fundamentally flawed, you may escape explosions by limiting the random range to `SIZE` (I haven't looked closely at your code to figure what its intention is).

---

Also, consider using a foreach loop. Instead of:

```
int SIZE;
for (int sizeI = 0; sizeI < sizeList.length; sizeI++) {
    SIZE = sizeList[sizeI];
```

Use just:

```
for (int SIZE : sizeList) {
```

And you may want to review the chapter on java naming standards while you're at it.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  I know my code isn't very pretty, that's something I need to work on.  Thanks for the additional optimization suggestions as well.

Answer (score 0):

for (int x : nums)
    counts[x - low]++;

This is wrong. From the ensuing code I think you want to do something like

```
int i =0;
for(int x:nums)
    counts[i++] = (x-low)++
```